# How to get an ec2 instance id from instance name

Tags: aws-powershell

i want to retrieve an ec2 instance's ID from it's name which I have set as the value of it's tag. I have a VM with key as 'Name' and value as 'testvm1'. Is there something like

`(get-ec2 instance id) | where-object {$_.(key.value) - eq "testvm1"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked

```
 $ec2Name = New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.Filter -Property @{Name = "tag:Name"; Values = "testvm1"}
    $instances = @(Get-EC2Tag -Filters $ec2Name) 
      $instances | Select-Object -ExpandProperty resourceid
```

Answer (score 2):

You can further reduce this by passing a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6) as your filter. This will map your input to a [Amazon.EC2.Model.Filter[]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TFilter.html) type.

Example with one filter on `tag:Name` mapping multiple tag names:

```
(Get-EC2Tag -Filter @{Name="tag:Name";Values="Name1","Name2"}).ResourceId
```

Example output:

```
i-abcd1234
i-edfg5678
```

Comment: Thanks @Anthony Neace